# WebAPI exception - Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this "known" issue below, but couldn't find a solution to that.
This works perfectly on my local VS2015, but fails in the remote 2008R2 server with IIS7.5.

```
"ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller
of type 'ProcessController'. Make sure that the controller has a
parameterless public constructor.",
```

Now, I've read all those hundreds of thread related to this, however, all are related to IoC and DI, which I'm NOT using in here.

I have tried adding a parameterless public constructor which didn't help. Still getting the same.

```
public ProcessController()
    {

    }
```

Again - this happens only in my remote server (Azure). Local is running with no issues.

There's an additional issue later on that is related to my interop dll which fails to register, but I'm not sure this is related.

Any help would be much appreciated...  Thanks

Comment: Is there any other controller with the same name "ProcessController"?

Comment: Are you using any IOC container? Ninject for example?

Comment: @MertAkcakaya - There isn't... if there was one I would have failed in my local VS as well. This now brings me an idea to set all remote site from scratch, just to be on the safe side.

Padraic - I'm not using any.

Comment: Just for the sake of testing I've renamed the ProcessController name to something else and got the same.

Comment: For some reason, this seems to actually DO related to my COM dll, as this error appears only when I'm trying to access a property of a class that is using this COM. 
However, strangely it still works after instantiating the class but fails only when I access a property of the class.

{"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CB4CF218-796A-4359-AA14-64EE3FA63772} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).}

Comment: @DaveGahan Were you able to find a resolution to this issue?  I'm having the same problem where I have two identical environmenets, but one throws this error and the other doesn't.